# Java - Append data to a text file kept on webserver

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to append some information to a text file kept on webserver using java using:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL("http://www.abcd.com/info.txt");
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("Established URL connection");
      }

      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setUseCaches(false);
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");

      System.out.println(connection.getOutputStream().toString());

      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
      writer.write("This is a sample text");
      writer.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Neither the text file is not being updated nor getting any error.. The reason for doing this is - I have developed a small software and the updates for this will be kept on web site. If any user updates the data, this code will update the text file. This way I will be able to get the information of user who have updated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you first need to get the data written in the file, to client, Using a GET call , then append the data, and the finally do a POST call to rewrite the file with appended data

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make the changes at server side to do that. You cannot acheive the same using `HttpURLConnection`.

You can try using `FTP` if its feasible for you. In case of FTP you should download the file, append the text and upload the same again.

Comment: Really didn't get your query. What you are trying to achieve looks like server side functionality. And you are trying to implement from client side. Any how HttpURLConnection will not support your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused - you're attempting to open an HTTP connection to a file and modify it on the fly?

I feel like I might be missing something - plain HTTP doesn't support this. Can you imagine the nightmare it would be if everybody could go around overwriting everybody else's websites (without authentication, even, as your code seems to suggest)?

What you're doing here is calling PUT on the `/info.txt` resource with your text as the entity body. I'm fairly sure that never has and never will overwrite the corresponding file.

What you need to do is either go through a protocol that supports file writing (WebDav, FTP...) or write server-side code that accepts a content submission (through, for example, a POST or PUT call with an entity body on a specific resource), analyses that input and modify its local file system.

Again, I might be misunderstanding your question entirely, in which case I apologise if I come off as somewhat patronising.

Comment: Doesn't really change my answer, though: you're still trying to write directly to a file through an HTTP connection, which isn't possible. You need to either write server-side code or connect through a protocol that supports file output.